# Infinite vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\mathbb{R^{\infty}}$ be the vector space consisting of all infinite sequences of real numbers $(x_1, x_2, x_3, . . .,x_{\infty})$.
Show that $\mathbb{R^{\infty}}$ has infinite dimensionality.

Need help on this question. I know the space is infinite dimensional because it includes all real numbers of various dimensions. 
Is there any other way to prove this?

Comment: Let $x_1 = (1,0,0,0,...)$ and $x_2 = (0,1,0,0,...)$ and $x_3 = (0,0,1,0,...)$ and so on. Can you show that $\{x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}, \dots\}$ is a linearly independent set? Assuming you can do this, can you explain why this implies the space is not finite dimensional?

Comment: @johnoliver Why do you want another way to prove this? If a vector space contains an $n$-dimensional subspace for every $n$, it follows directly that the space cannot be finite-dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

Prove that the sequences having $1$ at position $n$ and $0$ everywhere else are linearly independent.